# C# Selenium: ICapabilities does not contain a definition for BrowserName anymore

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core-2.1

On updating to Selenium 3.14.0 the BrowserName property is no longer a part of the ICapabilities API. Is there another way to get the browser name? I can't find updated documentation, is this expected behavior?

[image]

This is a .NET Core 2.1 targeted test suite (if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do this using something like the following code:

```
// Assumes the “caps” variable is a properly instantiated
// instance of ICapabilities. 
string browserName = string.Empty;
if (caps.HasCapability(“browserName”))
{
    browserName = caps.GetCapability(“browserName”).ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!