# Selenium C# | Trying to get browser name using ICapabilities but getting cast error

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Tried below code but getting cast error, even tried with as operator also

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
//ICapabilities caps = (ICapabilities)(driver as RemoteWebDriver);
ICapabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;

string browserName = string.Empty;
if (caps.HasCapability("browserName"))
{
      browserName = caps.GetCapability("browserName").ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(browserName);
```

Below is the error message

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver'.
```

Comment: I don't think you need to cast driver at all because the ChromeDriver implements ICapabilities.  Here is a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712212/c-sharp-selenium-icapabilities-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-browsername-an

Comment: and may need to use var for caps type instead of ICapabilities

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@Scott Mildenberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622056/scott-mildenberger), you are right no need to convert, driver implements ICapabilities.
Here is the update code for any one in need

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
ICapabilities caps = driver.Capabilities;

string browserName = string.Empty;
if (caps.HasCapability("browserName"))
{
      browserName = caps.GetCapability("browserName").ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(browserName);
Console.WriteLine(caps.GetCapability("browserVersion"));
```